# Executing multiple directives on a DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, tags

There are 2 directives defined in a module in AngularJs1.3

I find that only 1 directive gets executed ,though the 2 directives work individually when the other is commented out.
There are no exceptions in the execution console.

directive

```
angular.module('studentDetailApp.directives',[]).directive('studentDirective', function () {
    return {
    template:'...',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) { console.log('student directive');}
    }
})
.directive('basicDirective', function () {
    return {
    restrict:'E',
    template:'custom directive: {{textToInsert}}',
    link:function ($scope, element, attrs) { console.log('Printing out custom template');}
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="studentDetailApp">
<head>
    ....
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="StudentController"> 
      <basic-directive/>
      <div student-directive></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I find that the second directive works - while the first gets ignored.
What is the error?

Comment: its a typo, it should be `<basic-directive/>` and not `<basic-Directive/>`

Comment: Interestingly ,that is the directive which works(inspite of the case).It the first directive that gets ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close `basic-directive` element properly like `<basic-directive></basic-directive>`, element tags are not self closing in nature expect `img`, `br`, `hr`, etc. [**List of self closing tags**](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html)

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="StudentController"> 
     <basic-directive></basic-directive>
  <div student-directive></div>
</div>
```